# will the serialized data gets changed after every time program gets executed?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Iam trying to store multiple employee details using serialization,will the details be stored permanently or gets changed after every execution

```
Emp[] em2= (Emp[]) ois.readObject();
            for(Emp em3:em2 ){
                System.out.println(em3.id);
                System.out.println(em3.name);
                System.out.println(em3.age);
                System.out.println(em3.salary);
            }
            ois.close();
```

Comment: It will get changed every time you *serialize* it. Surely this is obvious?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what is happening with the serialized data. If you are persisting the serialized data to some file or db then no it won't change.

But if the serialized data is passed to some service which performs some action on it then persisting it to some storage and you access the data, then it will be changed.

**Edit**:

Every time data is written to the file make sure it is appended to the file, otherwise every time you run the program previous data will be overwritten.

Comment: iam storing it on to a file

Comment: ensure that data is appended to the file and not overwritten.

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: pass `true` while creating a `FileWriter` `fw = new FileWriter("output.txt", true);`

Comment: @harishhari did it work or is there any other issue?

Comment: yes the objects are getting stored but iam unable to retrive them from the file@Yug Singh

Comment: can you post in the question the issue you are getting while reading from file?

Comment: I have updated the question with code ,Iam able to read only the first object from the file@Yug Singh